# How to draw this 3d (tikz) picture more clearly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw this picture [(The GeoGebra Sketch)](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/m7sj4exs) in tikz and this is what I have currently

The picture compiles like this, which seems a bit messy since I can only assign a whole line to be solid or dashed and does not obey the realistic relation. Is there a way to improve it?
[image: this is what it compiles like]

My code shown below:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,positioning,3d,calc,fadings,shapes,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tikz,times,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{85}{20}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2,xscale=2,line width=0.5pt, tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,0,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (1,0,1);
    \coordinate (X) at (0,0,-1);
    \coordinate (H) at (1,0,-1);
    \coordinate (Y) at (2,0,1);
    
    \coordinate (A1) at (2,0,2);
    \coordinate (B1) at (2,1,2);
    \coordinate (C1) at (0,1,2);
    \coordinate (D1) at (0,0,2);
    \coordinate (E) at (1,-0.87,0.5);
    \coordinate (X4) at (0,-0.87,0.5);
    \coordinate (F) at (1,0.87,0.5);
    \coordinate (X5) at (0,0.87,0.5);
    \coordinate (X6) at (1,-0.87,1.5);
    \coordinate (X7) at (1,0.87,1.5);
    \coordinate (G) at (1,-0.87,-0.5);
    \coordinate (I) at (1,-1.73,0);
    \coordinate (Y2) at (1,-0.87,-1.5);
    \coordinate (Y3) at (2,-0.87,-0.5);
    \coordinate (Y4) at (2,0.87,-0.5);
    \coordinate (Y5) at (1,0.87,-0.5);
    \coordinate (J) at (1,1.73,0);
    \coordinate (Y6) at (1,0.87,-1.5);
    \coordinate (K) at (2,0,-1);
    \coordinate (M) at (2,1,1);
    \coordinate (N) at (1,0,1);
    \draw[rounded corners=0.05pt](A)circle (0.25pt)node[left=-2pt]{$A$}
    (B)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$B$}
    (C)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$C$}
    (D)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$D$}
    (E)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$E$}
    (F)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$F$}
    (G)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$G$}
    (H)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$H$}
    (I)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$I$}
    (J)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$J$}
    (X)--(A)--(X4)--(E)--(I)--(G)--(B)--(E)--(X6)--(D)--(B)
    (F)--(X7)--(D)
    (G)--(Y3)--(C)--(B)--(G)--(Y2)--(H)--(Y6)--(Y5)
    (Y4)--(C)--(Y)--(D)
;
    \draw[thin,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]
    (A)--(B)--(F)--(X5)--(A)
    (X)--(H)--(B)--(F)--(J)--(Y5)--(Y4)
    (B)--(Y5);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `intersections` to [define two paths](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.16): AB and EI.
Then, I computed the intersection which is a coordinate named `x`. All that is left is to draw two segments A--x--B (in red), on dashed and the other one not.

You can also play with [`dash pattern` option](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.3.2).

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,positioning,3d,calc,fadings,shapes,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tikz,times,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{85}{20}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2,xscale=2,line width=0.5pt, tdplot_main_coords]
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (1,0,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (2,0,0);
        \coordinate (D) at (1,0,1);
        \coordinate (X) at (0,0,-1);
        \coordinate (H) at (1,0,-1);
        \coordinate (Y) at (2,0,1);
        
        \coordinate (A1) at (2,0,2);
        \coordinate (B1) at (2,1,2);
        \coordinate (C1) at (0,1,2);
        \coordinate (D1) at (0,0,2);
        \coordinate (E) at (1,-0.87,0.5);
        \coordinate (X4) at (0,-0.87,0.5);
        \coordinate (F) at (1,0.87,0.5);
        \coordinate (X5) at (0,0.87,0.5);
        \coordinate (X6) at (1,-0.87,1.5);
        \coordinate (X7) at (1,0.87,1.5);
        \coordinate (G) at (1,-0.87,-0.5);
        \coordinate (I) at (1,-1.73,0);
        \coordinate (Y2) at (1,-0.87,-1.5);
        \coordinate (Y3) at (2,-0.87,-0.5);
        \coordinate (Y4) at (2,0.87,-0.5);
        \coordinate (Y5) at (1,0.87,-0.5);
        \coordinate (J) at (1,1.73,0);
        \coordinate (Y6) at (1,0.87,-1.5);
        \coordinate (K) at (2,0,-1);
        \coordinate (M) at (2,1,1);
        \coordinate (N) at (1,0,1);
        \draw[rounded corners=0.05pt](A)circle (0.25pt)node[left=-2pt]{$A$}
        (B)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$B$}
        (C)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$C$}
        (D)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$D$}
        (E)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$E$}
        (F)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$F$}
        (G)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$G$}
        (H)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$H$}
        (I)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$I$}
        (J)circle (0.25pt)node[below]{$J$};
        \draw
        (X)--(A)--(X4)--(E)--(I)--(G)--(B)--(E)--(X6)--(D)--(B)
        (F)--(X7)--(D)
        (G)--(Y3)--(C)--(B)--(G)--(Y2)--(H)--(Y6)--(Y5)
        (Y4)--(C)--(Y)--(D)
        ;
        \draw[thin,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]
        (B)--(F)--(X5)--(A) % <--------- removed (A)--
        (X)--(H)--(B)--(F)--(J)--(Y5)--(Y4)
        (B)--(Y5);
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \path [name path=AB] (A)--(B);
        \path [name path=EI] (E)--(I);
        \path [red,name intersections={of = AB and EI, by = x}];
        \draw [red](A)--(x); \draw [red,dashed] (x)--(B);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```